# Configure providers from variables, in a generic way

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, aws-opsworks

How can I create a recipe that will populate its attributes using the fiels from an instance of an object in a generic way?

As an example, consider the following recipe:

```
component = $auth_docker
docker_image component.name do
    registry component.registry
    tag component.tag
    action :pull
end
```

When you have 50s of recipes that look like this, maintaining them really gets overwhelming.

In Python, i would probably implement a solution that would look a bit like this:

```
docker_image = DockerImage(**$auth_docker)
```

Or, I would create some sort of helper function to build it for me:

```
def generate_docker_image_lwrp(attributes):
    lwrp = DockerImage()
    lwrp.registry = attributes.registry
    lwrp.tag = attributes.tag
    return lwrp
```

The goal is to reduce maintenance on the recipes. For instance this morning I wanted to add Chef's "retries" attribute on all recipes that pull an image. I had to edit all of them - I don't want that. I should've been able to a) add the attribute to the stack's JSON b) edit the Ruby wrapper class so that instances of it (i.e.: $auth_docker) get the "retries" field, then c) add the retries attribute to the lwrp-generator. Since all recipes would use the same generator, recipes wouldn't need to be edited at all.

Is this possible using Chef, in a way that 'notifies' still work?

Comment: Have you considered using `BasicObject#instance_eval` ? [#instance_eval](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/BasicObject.html#method-i-instance_eval)

Comment: Hm, no, my knowledge and experience of the Ruby language is very, very thin, and this is further complicated because Chef doesn't provide a totally pure Ruby context... Even after reading the doc you pasted, I'm not sure how I would use this against LWRPs. Any pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting the [Documentation](https://docs.chef.io/server_manage_cookbooks.html)

> A definition is code that is reused across recipes, similar to a
>   compile-time macro. A definition is created using arbitrary code
>   wrapped around built-in chef-client resources—file, execute, template,
>   and so on—by declaring those resources into the definition as if they
>   were declared in a recipe. A definition is then used in one (or more)
>   recipes as if it were a resource.
>
> Though a definition behaves like a resource, some key differences
>   exist. A definition:
>
> Is not a resource or a lightweight resource Is defined from within the
>   /definitions directory of a cookbook Is loaded before resources during
>   the chef-client run; this ensures the definition is available to all
>   of the resources that may need it May not notify resources in the
>   resource collection because a definition is loaded before the resource
>   collection itself is created; however, a resource in a definition may
>   notify a resource that exists within the same definition Automatically
>   supports why-run mode, unlike lightweight resources Use a defintion
>   when repeating patterns exist across resources and/or when a simple,
>   direct approach is desired. There is no limit to the number of
>   resources that may be included in a definition: use as many built-in
>   chef-client resources as necessary.

I.e: you can create a definition for this in a library cookbook used solely for this.

docker_library/defintions/default.rb

```
define :my_docker_image, :component => nil do
  component = params[:component]
  docker_image component.name do
    registry component.registry
    tag component.tag
    action :pull
  end
end
```

in your recipes (need to have a depends on the docker_library cookbook in the metadata.rb):

```
my_component = $auth_docker
my_docker_image my_component.name do 
  component my_component
end
```

A more complete exemple of definition is available in the [logrotate cookbook](https://github.com/stevendanna/logrotate/blob/master/definitions/logrotate_app.rb)

Comment: @Joe I made a typo on the resource call. Updating the answer

Comment: Thanks, this is definitely the way to go, although the parameters are in the params[] hash and cannot be accessed directly - I edited the answer to reflect that.