# Support multiple notifies in definitions

Tags: chef-infra

This is a followup question from [Configure providers from variables, in a generic way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30710479/configure-providers-from-variables-in-a-generic-way/30711835#30711835)

I wrapped some providers into definitions and I was wondering how to handle the notifies. I succeeded in writing a cheap implementation where I can pass an array of arrays, similar to this:

```
provider_definition name do
    component $some_component
    notifies [[:redeploy, "docker_container[some_container]", :immediately],
              [:redeploy, "docker_container[some_other_cntr]", :delayed]]
end
```

And then in my definition I have something like this:

```
params[:notifies].each do |notify_action, resource_name, notify_time|
    notifies notify_action, resource_name, notify_time
end
```

Surely there is a better way of doing this? I was hoping that I could keep the same kind of format in the recipe:

```
provider_definition name do
    component $some_component
    notifies :redeploy, "docker_container[some_container]", :immediately
    notifies :redeploy, "docker_container[some_other_cntr]", :delayed
end
```

But when I do this, only the last notifies makes it to my definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sticking with definitions you already have the better way I think.

An option to achieve what you wish would be to turn your definition into a LWRP, this will create a custom resource which can takes notify attributes as any other chef resource.

docker_library/resources/my_deploy.rb

```
action :deploy
default_action :deploy

attribute :component, kind_of: Hash, required: true
```

docker_library/provider/my_deploy.rb

```
action :deploy do
  params = new_resource.component
  docker_image params['name'] do
    registry params['registry']
    tag params['tag']
    action :pull
  end
end
```

I may be wrong on the type for the component, I let you adapt to your specific case. Written from memory, I may have forget something, there's more documentation [here](http://docs.chef.io/lwrp_custom.html) on LWRP.

And same as before in recipe, just that the LWRP name will be derived from cookbook name and file name, so in this case:

```
my_component = $auth_docker
docker_library_my_deploy my_component.name do 
  component my_component
  notifies :redeploy, "docker_container[some_container]", :immediately
  notifies :redeploy, "docker_container[some_other_cntr]", :delayed
end
```

Comment: Thanks again! Too bad there isn't a way to specify the same attribute multiple times.

Comment: I forgot the notify in the recipe Exemple ;)